# Is 'doo' a cajun term of endearment?

Tags: dialects

Paul Simon's zydeco-flavored song *That Was Your Mother* starts like this:

> A long time ago, yeah
>
> Before you was born dude
>
> When I was still single
>
> And life was great ...

At least these are the lyrics that I find online.

The use of "dude" strikes me as unlikely, incongruous, and sort of funny.
Anyway, I don't hear "dude", I hear "doo".
It seems to fit the song better if that phrase is a Cajun term of endearment.
Is there such a term in the Cajun dialect?

Comment: Note that Cajun is indeed a dialect, but of French, in addtion to English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Official Paul Simon Web Site](http://www.paulsimon.com/us/music/graceland/was-your-mother) shows "dude" as the correct lyric, with a copyright notice.

That said, "Doo" was used as a pet name in the movie "Coal Miner's Daughter", but that was a shortened version of the character's name, Doolittle.

Comment: Thanks. It's not the first time I've invented a convoluted explanation that turned out to be completely bogus.

Comment: You're hardly the [first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen).

Comment: @Byron  BTW, when you mishear a lyric from a song, its called Mondegreen.

Answer (score 2):

A "doo" or a "faydoo" is Cajun for "party".

Answer (score 0):

Doo (with the long o sound) can be used to tell your children to go to sleep.  "Go doo doo now."  But boo (with the ew sound) is used as a term of endearment.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense to me, in terms of the song. I couldn't understand why he was using California surfer's slang in a tender song to his son: Dude!